# How can I open file with .pdf.attachctrl extension?

Tags: pdf, adobe, adobe-reader

I have a file with .pdf.attachctrl extension. How can I open this file? I could not open with adobe reader. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you are speaking of the iPhone email app, with attachments extension “.attachctrl”

For the most widespread case, you need to open them with “MobileIron Docs@Work” app provided by your company IT. Those are encrypted attachments usually related to a company IT security hardening standard.